# Left join query isn't going as planned

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I currenty have a query that is supposed to do the following:

It checks in the Table 'Tafel' how much the 'maximum amount of players' is. Then it goes to the 'RoundRegistered' table to see if there are people already registered to that table.

What it does now is: it checks if there is a 'tafel' that isn't full yet. If that's the case it returns the FIRST one, so if there are more it doesn't care about them, it just  needs the first one.

But here's my issue: if there isn't atleast 1 record in the 'RoundRegistered' table, it won't find any 'Tafel' records. So what I wanted to do is a left join so it will still give back a 'Tafel' record under the same restrictions. The only thing that is blocking it (I think) is the HAVING..

```
SELECT T.* FROM TAFEL AS T
JOIN RoundRegistration AS RR ON RR.TafelID = T.ID
WHERE RR.RONDE = 1
GROUP BY T.ID
HAVING COUNT(RR.ID) < T.Max_Aantal_spelers
LIMIT 1
```

Anyone any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Theres no `LEFT` in that query.

Comment: @philipxy True, because a LEFT join doesn't return anything.. Probably because of the HAVING.

Comment: You need a left join to get rows for tables that don't appear in RoundRegistration (for the givein round).

Comment: Now below you seem to be telling us that RoundRegistration contains registration data for different tournaments as well as different rounds. What are the candidate keys (PRIMARY KEY and/or UNIQUE NOT NULLs) in your tables? Please show example table inputs, query, and desired output. If you can, say what a row states by being in each table & in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a left join

```
SELECT T.* FROM TAFEL AS T
LEFT JOIN RoundRegistration AS RR ON RR.TafelID = T.ID
WHERE RR.RONDE = 1
GROUP BY T.ID
HAVING COUNT(RR.ID) < T.Max_Aantal_spelers
LIMIT 1
```

Without the 'LEFT' clause you where doing an 'INNER JOIN'

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` clause is undoing the `LEFT JOIN`.  Move the condition to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM TAFEL T LEFT JOIN
     RoundRegistration RR
     ON RR.TafelID = T.ID AND RR.RONDE = 1
GROUP BY T.ID
HAVING COUNT(RR.ID) < T.Max_Aantal_spelers
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I added "AND RR.ToernooiID = 4" but it returned a row where 'ToernooiID' was 1.. xd So the AND doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @ThomasVieveen . . . I don't fully understand your comment.  If you add that condition, then you shoudln't see those values in the result set.